# How to get computer to stop crashing

Tags: 14.04, graphics, crash

I just recently got an old Windows Vista computer from a friend. However, I didn't have Widows Vista, or any OS, so I decided to get Ubuntu 14.04. I love it to bits and pieces, however It crashes all the time.

On to the crash:
It works fine for a while, to the point that I can even run Windows games on Wine perfectly. However, no matter what I'm doing, my system suddenly freezes and has to be rebooted via the power button. This only happens every few hours and there is no specific activity that causes the crash. However, I noticed that running graphics intensive applications (such as Minecraft, Blender, Audacity, etc.) tend to speed up the process making it crash after several minutes instead of a few hours.

**Here Are my System Specs:**

```
Memory: 7.8 GiB
Processor: Intel® Core™2 Duo CPU E6850 @ 3.00GHz × 2 
Graphics: Gallium 0.4 on NVA3
OS Type: 32-bit
Disk: 483.7 GB
```

Comment: *Gallium 0.4 on NVA3* means you have a Nvidia graphics but not installed the Nvidia proprietary drivers. Search for Additional Drivers in dash, select and apply the recommended version and reboot when done. This should improve the overall performance and avoid freezes (hopefully).

Comment: Please also run `sudo apt-get update` followed by `sudo apt-get install psensor` so that we can verify your temps are in check.